# Settings of Django for MongoDB Raises Error

Tags: python, django, mongodb, python-3.x, mongoengine

I want to use MongoDB in my application and [I used this documentation as reference](http://staltz.com/djangoconfi-mongoengine).

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy',
    }
}

SESSION_ENGINE = "mongoengine.django.sessions"

_MONGODB_HOST = "localhost"
_MONGODB_NAME = "erayerdin_blog"
_MONGODB_DATABASE_HOST = "mongodb://{}/{}".format(_MONGODB_HOST, _MONGODB_NAME)

mongoengine.connect(_MONGODB_NAME, host=_MONGODB_DATABASE_HOST)
```

Either `django.db.backends.dummy` or empty string simply raises `ImproperlyConfigured` if I want to `migrate`. How do I pass a dummy engine in Django anyway?

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

## Environment

- django 1.9.5
- mongoengine 0.10.6
- pymongo 3.2.2
- python 3.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior of the "Dummy" backend - it acts as a stub/default backend, it would start complaining if you actually [start to use it](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py#L61) - `migrate` tries to use the dummy backend.

Comment: So, does it really migrate with MongoDB, or not? I mean, is the process successfull even if it raises this error?

Comment: @ErayErdin I am not completely sure about that - from what I understand you should not be using `migrate` command if you are using mongoengine..

Comment: Hi guys, I have set up a `MongoDB` database and hooked it up to my `Django` backend. How do I remove the dummy stuff, so that when I run `migrate`, it uses the actual database? Is it true that I should remove the `DATABASES` section in my settings file if I am using a real database with `pymongo`?